# Angularjs Directory data executed before service called from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

Hi I was working with angular directive and i have created one...

```
  app.directive('customtable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '<table>';
            angular.forEach(scope[attrs.rows], function (row, index) {
                //html += '<tr><td>' + row.A+ '</td></tr>';
                html += '<tr><td>' + row.B+ '</td>' +
                '<td>' + row.C+ '</td>' +
                '<td>' + row.D+ '</td>' +
                '<td>' + row.E+ '</td>' +
                '<td>' + row.F+ '</td>' +
                '<td>' + row.G+ '</td>' +
                '<td>' + row.H+ '</td></tr>';
                if (index == 4) {
                    html += '<tr><td>' + 'Click Here to See All' + '</td></tr>';
                }
            })
            html += '</table>';
            element.replaceWith(html)
        }
    }
});
```

I am calling this directive from :

```
<table>
<tr customtable ng-model="data" rows="data" ng-hide="hideRows && $index > 4 && $index < (myArray.length - 5)">

</tr>
</table>
```

factory method :

```
dataFactory.getdate().success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result)   {
    $scope.data= result.data;
});
```

Here issue is As my scope variable $scope.data is getting set from factory method. first my directive code is getting executed and then the factory service gets called. so I am getting data variable undefined in directive code. any help and suggestions are most welcome. I am kind of stuck.

Comment: If you don't want isolated scope, you will probably have to watch the scope property and first check if it is defined.

Comment: do you mean i should watch scope property inside directive and what does it makes difference. I have less idea about watch property.

Comment: By using `attrs.rows` you are only seeing the text value "data". In the directive you don't have a two-way bind with the scope property.

Comment: @DavinTryon can you please elaborate more. I am not getting anything. sorry to bother you again.

Comment: for some background, why are you replacing a `<tr>` with a `<table>`?

Answer (score 0):

Create an isolated scope in your directive call data and put a watch on that scope variable.

Example: [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9Vw3I?p=preview) Pass in any additional information you need in your directive the same way.

```
.directive('customtable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          data: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '<table>';
            scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
              if (newValue === oldValue) return;
              angular.forEach(newValue, function (row, index) {
                  //html += '<tr><td>' + row.A+ '</td></tr>';
                  html += '<tr><td>' + row.B+ '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + row.C+ '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + row.D+ '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + row.E+ '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + row.F+ '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + row.G+ '</td>' +
                  '<td>' + row.H+ '</td></tr>';
                  if (index == 4) {
                      html += '<tr><td>' + 'Click Here to See All' + '</td></tr>';
                  }
              })

              html += '</table>';
              element.replaceWith(html)
            });


        }
    }
});
```